# How is $\mu$ the same as a renormalisation scale?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

I have been reading Schwartz's book on QFT. In the chapter on RG (chapter 23) he begins by reminding the reader of the running coupling for electric charge. Here he insists that the observable Coloumb potential $V(p)$ can be used to define a renormalised charge $e_R$ by $e_R^2=p_0^2 V(p_0^2)$.

He then goes on to derive the RG equation $p_0^2 \frac{d e_{\text{eff}}}{d p_0^2} = \frac{e_{\text{eff}}^3}{24 \pi^2}$ where $e_{\text{eff}}=p^2V(p^2)$.

Then he proceeds to talk about deriving the RG equations systematically from the counter terms and derives $\mu\frac{d e_{\text{eff}}}{d \mu} = \frac{e_{\text{eff}}^3}{12 \pi^2}$ with $\mu$ the renormalisation scale. This is essentially the same equation but with $p_0 \rightarrow \mu$.

So what is the connection between $p_0$ and $\mu$? How is it that they appear to be the same thing even though one was introduced to define the charge and the other was introduced to make dimensions work out? Or are they actually different?

Comment: You *defined* $p_0^2 = \mu^2$, essentially. I'm not sure what you mean by "the other was introduced to make dimensions work out". Are you talking about the appearence of $\mu$ in logarithms like $\ln(s/\mu)$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well the way  I understand $\mu$ is that you need to make the dimensions of the Lagrangian work out when you do dim. reg. I don't understand at which point $p_0^2=\mu^2$.

Comment: @Kris, do you know the difference beetween an "off-shell" and an "on-shell" renormalization scheme? The running of the coupling constant is usually expressed in term of the scale $\mu$ in an off-shell scheme. If you have the book, you might try to compare chaps. 10 and 15 of Mandl&Shaw, "QFT". They discuss the one-loop renormalization of QED in both the on-shell and off-shell scheme, using dimensional regularization to regulate the integrals.